# Where can I get aerial images for commercial use?

Tags: imagery, aerial-photography

Related question: [Free aerial map images for commercial use - Alternatives to Google maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/33973/3024)

I'm looking for a service that will allow me to download images at up to 1 meter resolution. Currently our system is based around the Mercator projection (pardon me if my terminology is incorrect) documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx). On this scale, we need imagery up to zoom level 17, which works out to be 1.2 meters per pixel.

The only quote online that I could find was from [Google Maps API for Business](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps-faq.html), which is $10,000 at the time of this writing. From what I can tell, the license doesn't allow images to be downloaded. Our system doesn't guarantee connection to the internet, so images will be pre-loaded.

Currently I'm using [MapQuest Open Aerial Tiles](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/map), but I need a little more coverage that that service provides.

If it matters, we don't charge for the images, but we do charge for the software that uses the images. Images are only a small part of the overall software, so we consider it to be a free service provided with the product.

What services exist that meet these requirements? I am willing to pay a license fee, provided it isn't ridiculous (<20,000 or so per year).

Comment: Which country are you from? How big is your Area of Interest? If you want satellite imagery for a small area, you could buy it from commercial Vendor.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I'm from the US, and most of the destinations will be in the US, but I will likely need areas around the globe. Destinations depend on where the clients are located.

Comment: In that case, I think your best option is to talk to ESRI Sales and see how you can integrate their web service (linked in one of the answers)

Answer (score 2):

What is your area of interest? You can download and use the NAIP imagery from 2011/2012 which is 1m as long as you can host your own service and cache/tile yourself. 
If you need outside the US, then Digital-Globe/GeoEye is going to be your prime vendor.

Comment: How do I get the imagery from NAIP? I'm not familiar with the service, and a cursory Google didn't turn up much information about how to get it, or what format it would be in. I'm totally fine with hosting my own service.

Comment: Here is the main link to it, http://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/ From here you can define the areas and it will process the files and provide links. There is other data available too

Answer (score 1):

What about esri, 1 meter or better in many parts of the world. http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=10df2279f9684e4a9f6a7f08febac2a9

Comment: Just a point to note: The Usage of the service is not free. There are many limitations. For a brief summery, see here: http://links.esri.com/agol_tou

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - Hmm, not exactly brief, but thanks for the link. Do they have some kind of API for getting the data without using their software? I need to be able to use this in another application we've built.

Comment: -1 Since this is not a good answer to the question... Devdatta raises a good point, the ESRI hosted services are not free and in some cases costly when using the ArcGIS Online/Cloud hosted services...

Answer (score 0):

DigitalGlobe provides several options, one being the [Global Base Map](http://www.digitalglobe.com/products#mapping&global-basemap) product.  (I am associated with DigitalGlobe.)

Comment: You answer would be more helpful, if you can provide links to Publicly available information about what Global Base Map is. Otherwise it is just self promotion.