# Free Web-service providing Satellite Images

Tags: openstreetmap, web-service, satellite

Is there any web-service currently available which is hosting satellite images as open-source, just like OSM web-service hosting vector maps? We want to make a real-time traffic monitoring commercial application for Turkey and want a hybrid map as our base-layer (OSM layer + Satellite Images with 50% transparency). Images where roads are easily visible are suffice and young images are more preferable.

Comment: This may not be an exact duplicate since you don't mention whether you're interested in commercial use, but take a look at [Free aerial map images for commercial use - Alternatives to Google maps](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33973/free-aerial-map-images-for-commercial-use-alternatives-to-google-maps)

Comment: How up to date or current r these images?

Comment: What resolution do you want the imagery? Mapquest has an satellite imagery layer. Nasa also has some layers on offer

Comment: @ all: I have updated my question to make it more detailed. And the mapquest doesn't looks to be sufficiently resolved for my purpose. Any other source?, where I can find better high-resolution satellite images or hybrid base-layers for better user experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Landsat is now available via Amazon Web Services

> Landsat 8 data is available for anyone to use via Amazon S3. All
>   Landsat 8 scenes from 2015 are available along with a selection of
>   cloud-free scenes from 2013 and 2014. All new Landsat 8 scenes are
>   made available each day, often within hours of production.

http://aws.amazon.com/public-data-sets/landsat/

To process this there are many open source tools coming out daily

> This step-by-step post walks through processing Landsat 8 imagery into
>   an interactive map that you can integrate into your website or app.
>   We’ll cover the process from finding and downloading the image data,
>   through processing it and adjusting its color balance, to bringing it
>   into TileMill and exporting it as an interactive web map – where it
>   can be combined with markers, animation, and other layers using
>   MapBox.js. We’ll use open source tools throughout, and many of the
>   techniques you’ll see will also apply to other satellite and aerial
>   data, like Landsat 7, MODIS, and even commercial imagery.

https://www.mapbox.com/blog/processing-landsat-8/